# как вызвать нужную секцию python

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, deeplearning4j

Я не знаком с питон, являюсь java разработчиком... Хочу написать приложение с микросервисной архитектурой. Часть сервиса использует дата сайнс, поэтому решил написать сервис на питоне. Наткнулся на пример: https://github.com/bansalshubh91/Image-Similarity-using-Deep-Ranking/blob/master/Train.py

А теперь вопрос: как мне вызвать секцию #Train Model  для формирования .ckpt файла?
Благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно уловил суть вопроса, то Вам нужно обернуть секцию `#Train Model` в метод (символ # в Python обозначает примечание).

В Python методы оформляются так:

```
def name_of_method (num_epochs):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        ....
```

где `def` - означает, что данная конструкция является методом, `name_of_method` - имя метода, `num_epochs` - аргумент. Тип возвращаемой переменной/объекта (в отличии от Java) указывать не нужно - при необходимости пишите `return something`, где `something` - это возвращаемый методом объект или значение переменной. Если не указан явно возврат `return`, то метод вернет `None`.

И далее в нужно месте сделать вызов этого метода, передав ему объект num_epochs:

```
name_of_method (num_epochs)
```

И не забывайте про отступы - в Python, в отличии от Java (где используются фигурные скобки `{}` и точку с запятой), разделение происходит с помощью отступов.

Comment: Не объединяйте два понятия [`функция` и `метод`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_(программирование)) в одно – `def` определяет и то, и другое. В отличие от Джавы, в Питоне функции могут существовать вне классов и не являться методами (как и в вашем примере, кстати).